# Twitter4J Failed request token

Tags: android, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

Hi i'm using [this tutorial](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-post-twitter-status-from-android/comment-page-2/)

for my twitter test project and i already change :

from

> mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", "http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

to

> mHttpOauthprovider = new DefaultOAuthProvider("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token","https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize");

my problem is, when my apps in https://dev.twitter.com/apps/, if i didn't fill Callback URL in that edittext, I will get error :

> 05-08 11:47:08.070: W/System.err(20424): oauth.signpost.exception.OAuthCommunicationException: Communication with the service provider failed: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
>   05-08 11:47:08.070: W/System.err(20424):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:214)
>   05-08 11:47:08.070: W/System.err(20424):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveRequestToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:69)
>   05-08 11:47:08.070: W/System.err(20424):     at sg.tv.SocialGate.TwitterCore.TwitterApp$2.run(TwitterApp.java:152)
>   05-08 11:47:08.070: W/System.err(20424): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token
>   05-08 11:47:08.075: W/System.err(20424):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:177)
>   05-08 11:47:08.075: W/System.err(20424):     at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:271)
>   05-08 11:47:08.075: W/System.err(20424):     at oauth.signpost.basic.HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.getContent(HttpURLConnectionResponseAdapter.java:18)
>   05-08 11:47:08.075: W/System.err(20424):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.handleUnexpectedResponse(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:228)
>   05-08 11:47:08.080: W/System.err(20424):     at oauth.signpost.AbstractOAuthProvider.retrieveToken(AbstractOAuthProvider.java:189)
>   05-08 11:47:08.080: W/System.err(20424):     ... 2 more

but when I fill that Callback URL I didnt get any issue. But I want to left that Callback URL edittext blank, how to solve that issue? thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Twitter to redirect to a callback url you should enter 'oob' indicating an out-of-bound authentication sequence. In this case the user will be presented with a PIN that they need to enter into your application to complete the authorization flow.

Comment: how to change into that flow?? because i just follow the flow from above tutorial